# Sortable BindingList<T>: confusion about RemoveSortCore

Tags: c#, .net, bindinglist

I'm implementing my own `BindingList<T>` that supports sorting. Everything is working well so far, but I'm confused about how I should implement [`RemoveSortCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132701.aspx). The documentation is not very explicit, it only says:

> Removes any sort applied with ApplySortCore if sorting is implemented in a derived class

Does that mean I should restore the original order of the items? The implementation shown in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx) only sets `_isSorted` to false, without actually restoring the original order, which makes it quite useless IMHO...

If I want to be able to restore the original order, I guess I need to maintain a copy of the original collection (or is there a better way?). But if I do that, how do I handle modifications of the collection while it is sorted?

- When overriding `InsertItem`, should I just add the new item at the end of the unsorted copy?
- When overriding `RemoveItem`, I'm given the index in the sorted collection. But it means that if I want to also remove the item from the unsorted collection, I need to find its original position, which is an O(n) operation, while `RemoveItem` is normally expected to be an O(1) operation. The same question also applies to `SetItem`.

How would you handle that? Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is up to the implementer to define exactly what this means.  The two most obvious choices are:

1. Revert the list to the original form: Official example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480736.aspx)
2. Remove the Sort and proceed as if one had never been applied: As used in [MS.SqlServer.Management.Controls.SortableBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff488724%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the first article is just what I was looking for!